# Are tickets to Khao Yai National Park multi-entry?

Tags: thailand, national-parks

Is it possible to leave [Khao Yai National Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khao_Yai_National_Park) and enter again a few hours later (without buying new tickets for people and vehicles)?

I am interested in any procedure allowing this, for example telling staff and having them stamp your hands and having them take down your license plate. If this is (only) possible when renting a room in the park then that also answers the question (in the affirmative).

The reason for asking is that there are a number of restaurants just outside the park, but one(s) within the park were unsatisfactory last time.

I am especially interested in the procedure for multi-day park visits (where meals are more of a factor as well). I've stayed on the same ticket before when sleeping one night in the park but without attempting to reenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-enter in the same day for sure.
But for multi-day, it is upon the staff decision. They do not have clear regulation on this.

Comment: Do you have any references for this? Are you supposed to keep the tickets and can they be used on the same day? Is there no mechanism to prevent giving the tickets to others so they could enter for free?

Comment: The ticket have date stamped. I have experienced travel in and out in the same day to dine around without problem.